# Can I use GPU to bake fluid simulation?

Tags: baking, gpu, fluid-simulation

I have 8 Tesla K80 GPUs that I want to use! I do not want to use cpu it would be slower right?

Comment: Can I have one please? :D

Answer (score 4):

At current point the answer is - no.

You can use GPU for:

- Cycles rendering
- Subsurf
- Compositing